# Proximo Heroku addon is timing out

Tags: heroku, proximo

I have a simple node proxy that I have added proximo to use whitelisting for an API. It worked before, but having followed the tutorial I now get this in my logs:

```
2014-08-19T16:23:21.376311+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/?url=http://www.google.com" host=warm-cliffs-7633.herokuapp.com request_id=ecf77eea-a027-4115-86ff-5acf527c7333 fwd="82.24.137.140" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=623
```

If I try to access the page, I get an error message, but the page works fine if no URL is requested from the proxy.

There isn't very much documentation and I'm not sure if this is right in my Procfile:

```
web: bin/proximo node proxy.js
```

Comment: I have a very similar problem to this right now, did you ever resolve this?

Comment: Nope. I emailed them, didn't get a resolution, so I ended up moving to nodejitsu because they had static IPs by default. Nodejitsu seems to have shut down now!

Comment: Damn :/, thanks for the response, I've mailed the Proximo support so hopefully they can help resolve it. I couldn't get the similar Fixie to work either.

Comment: Did you find an answer?